# $\log(1-\cos (x-t)) \in \mathcal{L}^2([0,2\pi]^2)$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, integral-equations

[image: 1]

I'm currently studying on symmetric kernels of integral equations and here is the problem from Raisinghania textbook "Integral Equation and Boundary Value Problems". It is obvious that the kernel is symmetric since $$K(x,t)=\log(1-\cos (x-t))=\log(1-\cos (t-x))=K(t,x).$$
My question here is how can we know that $\log(1-\cos (x-t)) \in \mathcal{L}^2([0,2\pi]^2)$. It's not in the exercise questions, it's just my thoughs. We see that $\forall x,t:$ $x=t$ we have $K(x,x)=\log(0)= - \infty$. This part confuses me the most to prove that $K(x,t) \in \mathcal{L}^2([0,2\pi]^2)$. Any explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the decomposition
$$ K(x,t)=-\log(2)-2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)\cos(nt)}{n}-2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)\sin(nt)}{n} $$
it is straightforward that $K\in \mathcal{L}^2((0,2\pi)^2)$, since $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}\in\ell_2$.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. Is there another way to prove this before knowing this decomposition? Although is there a way to get those bilinear series in the standard ways by looking for eigenfunctions?

Comment: @Karagum: the bilinear series can be deduced from the Fourier series of $\log\sin$, since $\log(1-\cos z)=\log 2+2\log\left|\sin(z/2)\right|\in\mathcal{L}^p((0,2\pi))$ for any $p\geq 1$.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much! Also, it was pretty clear ho to get $\lambda_0$ and $y_0$ and the form of eigenfunctions $y_n=A \cos(nx) + B \sin (nx)$ bus I'm not really sure how to get the eigenvalue for $y_n$, $n \geq 1$. Can you help me with that?